# Efficiency of multiple chained str transformation and alternatives

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm wanting to change a dataframe column so the values are lower case and also have their whitespace stripped.

For this I used chained `str` transformations.

```
df.loc[:, column] = df.loc[:, column].str.lower().str.strip()
```

The above snippet works, but it looks quite messy as I have to use `.str.` twice - is there a better/more efficient solution?

Comment: Use a list comprehension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
df['col2'] = [x.lower().strip() for x in df['col']]
```

Doing this can be faster than chaining multiple `str`:

```
%%timeit
df['col2'] = df['col'].str.strip().str.lower()
# 344 ms ± 12.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df['col2'] = [x.lower().strip() for x in s]
# 182 ms ± 3.13 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

used input (1M rows):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['  aBc  DeF    ']*1000000})
```

*NB. I used `strip` before `lower` in the comparison as this is faster than `lower`, then `strip`.*

##### non string values in the input

If there are non string values, the list comprehension will fail.

There are several possibilities to handle this.

###### Using a systematic check:

```
df['col2'] = [x if pd.isna(x) else x.lower().strip() for x in df['col']]
```

this will however add an extra burden and will probably be slower compared to only two chained `str` (but might still be faster than more than 2 chained `str`).

###### Using a custom function and try/except:

try/except has a very low cost **if no error is triggered**, which might make it a viable solution when the number of non-string values is low. In this case one would use:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return x.lower().strip()
    except:  # add exhaustive expected exceptions if known
        return x

df['col2'] = [f(x) for x in df['col']]
```

timings (1M rows with 1% non-string values):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.random.choice(['  aBc  DeF    ', float('nan')],
                                           p=[0.99, 0.01], size=1000000)})

%%timeit
df['col2'] = df['col'].str.strip().str.lower()
349 ms ± 18.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df['col2'] = [x if pd.isna(x) else x.lower().strip() for x in df['col']]
442 ms ± 11.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df['col2'] = [f(x) for x in df['col']]
235 ms ± 2.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: but failed if missing values

Comment: @jezrael yes in this case adding an extra check (e.g. `[x if pd.isna(x) else x.lower().strip() for x in df['col']]`) will make the list comprehension slower, but it might still be faster if you have more that 2 `str`

Comment: Agree, best add to answer.

Comment: @jezrael good suggestion, I added it. A solution with try/except is still faster than 2 chained `str` (for a low number of non strings) ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['ABCD    EFG', 'ABC  DE'], columns=['col1'])
df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['col1'].lower().strip(), axis=1)
```